# Using the Taylor expansion to get the solution of a differential equiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, initial-value-problems

I've got stuck with this differential equation. I've to solve the problem using the *exponential expansion*.

$$
y'(x) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
y
\text{ }\text{ }; 
y(1) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let's get $A^n$:

$$
A^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 \\
2 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ }\text{ }
A^3 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 4 \\
4 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ }\text{ }
...
\text{ }\text{ }
A^n =
2^{n-1} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We can do the exponential expasion like:

$$
e^{Ax} = 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(Ax)^n}{n!} = 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n-1} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 
\frac {1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^n}{n!} =
\frac {1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}e^{2x}
$$

So that,  I think the solution should be:

$$
y(x) = \frac {C}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}e^{2x}
$$

But I think this is wrong because it looks like it's impossible to get the particular solution:

$$
y(1) = \frac {1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
C_1 \\
C_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
e^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

As you can see, this is not possible to get a solution from this equation.

Does anyone know where I made a mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula
$$
A^n =
2^{n-1} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is not correct for $n=0$.
$$
e^{Ax} = 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(Ax)^n}{n!} = 
I+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{n-1} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \frac{x^n}{n!} = I+
\frac {1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^n}{n!} 
$$
$$
= I+\frac12\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}+
\frac {1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^n}{n!} -\frac12\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
=
I+\frac {1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}e^{2x}-\frac12\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$